# "init exec providers default locations" Error when Starting Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am facing an error as per image when I start eclipse. Can anyone advise me how I can remove the error?

not sure whether  it would affect usage, but I just find the error to be annoying

[image: Eclipse Error]

P.S.: Prior to this, I installed 2020-06...then uninstall it by deleting eclipse, .eclipse folder in users\myUser\ afterwards, I install 2020-03 and this started happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error message when starting Eclipse 2020-06.
After updating from 2020-03 to 2020-06 I hadn't this problem.

It might be a coincidence but if I rembember correctly it started to appear when I updated the SAP Development Tools to the latest version.

Update:
In my Eclipse .log file I can see the following error message:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 0 2020-07-15 17:02:45.692
!MESSAGE init exec providers default locations
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2020-07-15 17:02:45.692
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "GRUNT default location".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sap.xst4e.exttools.exec.GruntExecProvider.getGlobalInstLocation(GruntExecProvider.java:104)
    at com.sap.xst4e.exttools.exec.GruntExecProvider.getDefaultLocation(GruntExecProvider.java:42)
    at com.sap.xst4e.exttools.internal.PreferenceInitializer.lambda$8(PreferenceInitializer.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job$2.run(Job.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: I can confirm that I also have the SAP development tools installed, and I now have this massage. So we have to look for a solution somewhere in that direction.

Comment: SAP seems already to work on a solution. I created an answer on https://answers.sap.com/questions/13093498/error-message-with-eclipe-2020-06-since-updating-t.html. There is answer from a SAP guy called Thomas Fiedler that states:

"Hi community,

we found an issue in the area of CAP tooling. Fix will be provided asap.

Sorry for that.

Regards,

Thomas."

Answer (score -1):

I have updated to the latest version and the issue seems to have been fixed.